# Is there a way of changing the labels and levels of the nomogram in the hdnom package?

Tags: r, plot

I have created a nomogram from smart dataset using hdnom package. I have shared the codes and the image of the nomogram below. The hdnom package allows only use of integer variables for factors and therefore the levels of the integer variables are only 0 and 1.

```
data(smart)
x <- as.matrix(smart[, -c(1, 2)])
time <- smart$TEVENT
event <- smart$EVENT
y <- survival::Surv(time, event)
fit <- fit_aenet(x, y, nfolds = 10, rule = "lambda.1se", seed = c(5, 7), parallel = F)
nom <- as_nomogram(fit, x, time, event,pred.at = 365 * 2,funlabel = "2-Year Overall Survival Probability")

plot(mynom)
```

This reveals the following image. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujjld.png]

I want to change the variable labels to "Abdominal aortic stenosis (yes/no)", "Stenosis (yes/no)","IMT (yes/no)" ,"Albumin (ng/mL)" and I want to change the levels from 0 and 1 to "No" and "Yes" in this nomogram. I tried to change the labels of the variables before fitting it into the model. But I failed.
I would really appreciate if someone can guide me how to change those variables levels and labels.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi I would really appreciate anybody helping me with this...thanks